# Goodness on test or train set?

Tags: regression, data, logistic-regression, chi-square-test, goodness-of-fit

I split my data set before on train (80%) and test (20%) splits. Trained logistic regression model on the train set. Now, want to check the goodness of fit using the Chi-square likelihood omnibus test, on what data set I should apply it to test or train?

Comment: I don't understand, what do you want to test exactly? Which statement are trying to prove or disprove?

Answer (score 0):

You should apply to the Test data as you already trained your model with training data.